# customizing the sort rows in a report

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to totally customize my report rows.  Say I have a matrix report like this:

```
Category         Smith         Jones          Johnson
Overhead         1,230.00      34.00          56.01
FTE              (23.00)       105.00         2,389.00
RVU              3.00          787.00         89.00
Salary           44.00         782.00         9.00
Subsidy          11.00         4,561.00       389.00
TNS              4635.00       55.00          45.00
```

Is it possible to create a totally custom sort order?  I would like to move RVU on top, then Salary, then TNS, etc.  I found if I go into the Group Properties, I can define an expression like:

```
 =iif(Fields!City.Value=”RVU”,”1″, iif(Fields!City.Value=”Salary”,”2″, iif(Fields!City.Value=”TNS”,”3″,”"...etc.
```

But that's very restrictive, and if I later want to move a row up or down, I have to go in and change all the numbers.  What I'm looking for is a drag and drop approach that would let me change the order easily, and at any time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Thank you.This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding a sort order to your dataset, it is the easiest to maintain, maybe a case sentence in your sql query,

```
Select Case when [Category]='RVU' then 1 
 when [Category]='Salary' then 2 end as Sortorder, [other], [columns]
```

then you can order by the sort order column

I can't think of an easy drag and drop solution to this problem